# Use a C# Check to determine value for JQuery parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I've got this; however it sadly does not work.

```
$("#plannedShippingInputBox").datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", constrainInput: true,
minDate: @Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")) < 20) ? 0 : 1
,
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends});
```

It's about this part:

```
minDate: @Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")) < 20) ? 0 : 1
```

I'd like to determine the minDate by the the hour. If it's before 20:00 (8PM), I want the customer to choose for today. If it's past 8PM, they'd have to select 'tomorrow'.

Any ideas?

Comment: `minDate: @Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")) < 20 ? 0 : 1 ` try this. You have extra closing `)`

Comment: why is minDate suppose to be 1 or 0 that doesn't makes much sense shouldn't it be a date?

Comment: Why are you parsing the Hours as a string when you have an integer property on them already `DateTime.Now.Hour`

Comment: You are missing an open parenthesis.  Maybe that's why?  `minDate: @(Int32.Parse(...`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Perfect! I'm so stupid!

Comment: @Paramone no worries, typo happens :)

Comment: @johnny5 The number 0 or 1 are the days being added today. Meaning if Today is Tuesday, 0 stays Tuesday. 1 is Tuesday + 1 day = Wednesday.

Comment: @johnny5 I wanted to make sure it's not the 12h format. Adding HH ensures it's the 24h format.

Comment: Cool it might be more clear if you renamed that property from minDate to number of days to add,  why are you parsing the hours instead of using the property thou

Comment: @johnny5 https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: Damn, jQuery did that.  Their programming offends me hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var hour='@(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"))';
minDate: parseInt(hour) < 20 ? 0 : 1
```